# Macro copying blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have this macro:

In sheet 1 it selects all values in Column A, then select only constants, then select filter and copy that filtered values in column A and paste it in another list. Then again, but with next column.

Problem is when that **filtered** column get empty. When there are some values, there is no problém, but when filtered column is empty, Im getting runtime error. How can I solve this please?

[image: just small quick example]

Here my Macro would copy only Column A and Column B, and when it get to Column C I get error and it wont continue..
[image: after filter]

UPDATED:

Ex. 1:

```
'   PO DC2 O
Sheets("Celkový harmonogram").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Průřez_dispečer32111").ClearManualFilter
Range("Tabulka141121518[13]").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Průřez_dispečer32111")
    .SlicerItems("Bodnariucová Renáta").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("Kajer Roman").Selected = True
End With

If Application.CountIf(Selection, "<>0") < 1 Then GoTo Line442
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("jednotlivci").Select
Range("Y6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

'   UT DC2 R
Line442:
Sheets("Celkový harmonogram").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Průřez_dispečer32111").ClearManualFilter
Range("Tabulka141121518[14]").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Průřez_dispečer32111")
...
```

Ex. 2: (error with empty cells)

```
If Application.CountIf(myRange, "<>0") > 0 Then
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("jednotlivci").Select
Range("Y6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Else: GoTo Line442
End If
```

Ex. 3: (type mismatch error at "If.." line)

```
If Application.CountIf(Selection, "<>0") < 1 Then GoTo Line442

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("jednotlivci").Select
Range("Y6").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Test the column filter if empty go to End Sub

Comment: Im beginner with VBA, this macro Ive done with recording. Can you help me with that test please? I suppose something like "If Selection = "" then Go To End" or something like that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Before with write: If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2").Value <> "" Then and Endif at the end F2 is the first condition of your filter sheet1 is  the sheet where you wrote the filter

Comment: I edited the code in the post. When I run it, I get error. Something in that If ... And just to add - at first, in the UNfiltered column, there are data, but also blank cells, and so when I filter it and there is blank cells only, its not working.

Comment: Also I have longer code than only this. In complete macro code I have code for copying data from 15 columns, this is just for one column.

Comment: @RomanŽydyk yass made a point but need to be careful what `Range.Value` means. Use this instead: `If application.CountIf(myRange, "<>0") > 0 Then ...`; where `myRange` is the range that you want to check if it is empty. You can set a range like this: `Set myRange = Sheets("something").Range("F2:G100")`

Comment: Edited original post

Comment: @RomanŽydyk Do you get the error when the range is completely empty or if there's empty cells within it?

Comment: @RomanŽydyk `Else` doesn't need colon after it. (For the Ex. 2)

Comment: I got error when filtered range is empty. In whole column is always some data, but when filtered, could happen that some column will be empty.

Colon after Else was automatically added by Excel, idk why.

Comment: Try `CountA` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added three line to your code. They checks to see if your selection/range is empty and then exit the sub if so. You need to run this code and maybe remove the if-statement that you already added (`.Value` does not make that much sense  to me). Also, you need to check which if-statement that I added resolves the original error you mentioned first in your question (most probably you will end up having only the third one).

```
Sheets("Celkový harmonogram").Select
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Průřez_dispečer32111").ClearManualFilter
Range("Tabulka141121518[13]").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Select

'This is the part added (if you get the error in the following lines):
If Application.CountIf(Selection, "<>0") < 1 Then Exit Sub
'This will exit the sub; you can also "GoTo" a line as error handler or _
'Skip one step of a loop as you mentioned you are doing this for number of columns.

With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Průřez_dispečer32111")
    .SlicerItems("Bodnariucová Renáta").Selected = False
    .SlicerItems("Kajer Roman").Selected = True
End With

'Also this cause it's not clear where you exactly get the error:
If Application.CountIf(Selection, "<>0") < 1 Then Exit Sub
'OR
If Application.CountIf(Sheets("Celkový harmonogram").Range("Tabulka141121518[13]") _
 , "<>0") < 1 Then Exit Sub


If Sheets("Celkový harmonogram").Range("Tabulka141121518[13]").Value <> "" Then
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("jednotlivci").Select
    Range("Y6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End If
```

Instead of `Exit Sub` you can go to another line like this:

```
If Criteria Then 
isError = True
GoTo ErrorHandler
End If

'Rest of the code in case of no error
'...

ErrorHandler:
If IsError Then
'Code you want to be performed in case of error
End If
```

Notice: The second if-statement is added to avoid running error handler in case of no error (VBA runs everything and won't skip ErrorHandler block).

Comment: Thank you, maybe that second If could work, but how to edit it to not End Sub, but to skip to another line?

Comment: @RomanŽydyk write `GoTo SkipLine` and then have `SkipLine:` at the beginning of your wanted section. Will add it to my code shortly.